# Javascript reads my date String as number, when I pass my data with ModelAndView(Spring)

Tags: javascript, spring, date, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use Spring Boot framework and Thymeleaf to build my program.

When I pass my date String with ModelAndView in my controller as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
public ModelAndView search() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("exchangerate");
    List<String> timeList = new ArrayList<>();
    timeList.add("2017/07/21");
    timeList.add("2017/07/24");
    timeList.add("2017/07/25");
    timeList.add("2017/07/26");
    view.addObject("timeList",timeList);
    return view;        
}
```

And

```
<script>
    var yAxis = [[${timeList}]];
    var yAxis2 = ['2017-07-21', '2017-07-24', '2017-07-25', '2017-07-26'];
    console.log(yAxis);
    console.log(yAxis2);
</script>
```

What I see in console is

```
[13.721088435374151, 12.005952380952381, 11.525714285714287, 11.082417582417584]

["2017-07-21", "2017-07-24", "2017-07-25", "2017-07-26"]
```

So I guess it reads `yAxix` as number.

What can I do if I want to use `yAxis` as String or Date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
```

will fix this. It should output it as a list of quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple to understand why this happens.

When you send it to the JavaScript for processing, JSON.parse actually interprets your dates as `(2017/07)/21`, which gets evaluated to the floating decimals you see. This implies that your dates are not getting converted into strings for JSON before being sent further.

As a remedy, either consider sending your dates wrapped in a proper date object from Spring end, or consider stringifying your dates before you send them using a JSON mapper at the Spring end.